# Qt Application Icon doesn't work

Tags: c++, icons, qt5

I created a small .ico for my program. Now I want Qt to set it as the applications icon.

I found this documentation but it doesn't seem to work : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/appicon.html

I did exactly what they want me to do.

1. Create an myapp.rc file and write `IDI_ICON102 ICON DISCARDABLE "Movie-World.ico"` 
   into it. -> Did that.
2. Write `RC_FILE += myapp.rc` into your .pro file.
   -> Did that.

When I compile and run, it doesn't work. I deleted the realese folder but still no changes. I restarted Qt but still no changes.

I even added `win32:` before `RC_FILE += myapp.rc` but it did not work...

I don't understand why. My files are all in the same directory.

Now I get this error message :

> mingw32-make[1]: *** No rule to make target '..\Qt', needed by
>   'release/myapp_res.o'.  Stop. makefile:34: recipe for target 'release'
>   failed mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2 18:11:33: The process
>   "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project Project1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.1
>   MinGW 32bit) When executing step 'Make'

Comment: Regenerate your makefile and your application, also try RC_FILE = myapp.rc as it is exactly in Qt docs

Comment: I tried that as well but it did not work.

Comment: are you sure the path to your .ico is correct?

Comment: I put it exactly where all my other files are. The myapp.rc is there as well.

Comment: @computer I got an error message now, it's really strange =/ Also, it works when I create a new project. I created Project 2, really simple and it has an icon now.

Comment: so what exactly did you do that it started to work in different project? = instead of +=?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37421/discussion-between-davlog-and-computer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should

- go to project on the left side of Qt Creator
- press right mouse button and
- “Run Qmake”

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the folder containing my project has a space in the name. When I removed the space, it worked.